# GPAC MPEG-DASH Reusing Live Profile Chunked Video for On-Demand Playback

Tags: video, live-streaming, mpeg, mpeg-dash

I am trying to re-use a set of MPEG-DASH videos that were originally generated using a live profile but now need replaying.

After a bit of playing around it seems more complicated than I had originally anticipated simply changing the type from `dynamic` to `static` didn't work presumably because we are also missing details like the end of the video which obviously wouldn't be present in a live scenario but are with on-demand. I know that I could re-build the full .mp4 of the stream and then re-chunk as on-demand but that seems the wrong way to do it. Also Mozilla state [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Setting_up_adaptive_streaming_media_sources):

> You can use the same media files for both live transmission and VOD at a later stage

So there must be some way to do it...

Here is the manifest file from the original broadcast `live.mpd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.6.2-DEV-rev135-g2dd7b95-master  at 2016-04-07T11:49:25.297Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT4.000S" type="dynamic" publishTime="2016-04-07T11:49:25Z" availabilityStartTime="2016-04-07T11:49:05.259Z" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT0H0M2.000S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M4.011S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011">
    <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://192.168.1.103:8080/recording_29/">
        <Title>1</Title>
    </ProgramInformation
    <BaseURL>http://192.168.1.103:3000/bbc_apr16/uhd0/recording_29/</BaseURL>

    <Period id="GENID_DEF" start="PT0H0M0.000S">
        <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="und">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="live_$RepresentationID$_$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="360000" initialization="live_$RepresentationID$_.mp4"/>
            <Representation id="audio" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="48000" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="6868">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="3840" maxHeight="2160" maxFrameRate="25" par="16:9" lang="und">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="live_$RepresentationID$_$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="360000" initialization="live_$RepresentationID$_.mp4"/>
            <Representation id="video_2160p" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42c01f" width="3840" height="2160" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="31726550">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_720p" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42c01f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="3175420">
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

If I play this back as is it tries to retrieve live files (which obviously don't exist) from now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so its actually a lot simpler than I expected!

You first need to change `type="dynamic"` to `static`. That should allow the file to be played as if it was a live broadcast again, no scrub bar...

To get the scrub bar back we need to set the `mediaPresentationDuration`. To set this we need to count the number of segments then multiply that by the segment duration in my case `4000` milliseconds. Then put this is the format `PT1H22M12.000S`.

So in this manifest we can playback the files with the following adjusted manifest (Note my BaseURL was also wrong...):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.6.2-DEV-rev135-g2dd7b95-master  at 2016-04-07T11:49:25.297Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT4.000S" type="static" publishTime="2016-04-07T11:49:25Z" availabilityStartTime="2016-04-07T11:49:05.259Z" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT0H0M2.000S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M4.011S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" mediaPresentationDuration="PT1H22M12.000S">
    <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://192.168.1.103:8080/recording_29/">
        <Title>1</Title>
    </ProgramInformation>

    <Period id="GENID_DEF" start="PT0H0M0.000S">
        <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="und">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="live_$RepresentationID$_$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="360000" initialization="live_$RepresentationID$_.mp4"/>
            <Representation id="audio" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="48000" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="6868">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="3840" maxHeight="2160" maxFrameRate="25" par="16:9" lang="und">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="live_$RepresentationID$_$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="360000" initialization="live_$RepresentationID$_.mp4"/>
            <Representation id="video_2160p" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42c01f" width="3840" height="2160" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="31726550">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_720p" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42c01f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="3175420">
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

I created a little script to do all this its on [GitHub](https://github.com/GerryWilko/MPD-L2OD).